# Azure-pipeline Build and Deploy to Google Cloud Stuck after Gcloud Auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, azure-pipelines, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a cicd pipeline using Azure DevOps. But after running gcloud auth configure-docker my job is stuck for hours with no response on the pipeline logs.

[image]

This is how my azure-pipelines.yml looks like

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest' # other options: 'macOS-latest', 'windows-latest'

jobs:
- job: BuildAndDeploy
  steps:
  - script: echo Building and Deploying your Rails app...
    displayName: 'Build and Deploy'
  
  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    name: authkey
    displayName: 'Download Service Account Key'
    inputs:
      secureFile: 'xxx.json'
      retryCount: '2'
    
  - script: |
      # Log in to Google Cloud using the service account key
      gcloud auth activate-service-account xxx --key-file $(authkey.secureFilePath)
      gcloud auth configure-docker
      
      # Build the Docker image
      docker build -t gcr.io/xxx-xxx/my-rails-app .
      
      # Push the Docker image to GCR
      docker push gcr.io/xxx-xxx/my-rails-app:latest
    displayName: 'Build and Push Docker Image'
```

I tried pushing and deploying an image from my local to gcloud. It is working fine.

I tried using the docker-compose task from the Azure pipeline and the docker task as well but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add error validation and timeout in your pipeline code as below:

```
     # Push the Docker image to GCR
      docker push gcr.io/xxx-xxx/my-rails-app:latest
    displayName: 'Build and Push Docker Image'
    timeoutInMinutes: 10 # Set timeout for this step to 10 minutes

  - script: |
      # Add error validation step here
      # For example, check if the Docker image was successfully pushed to GCR
      if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error: Docker push failed"
        exit 1
      fi
    displayName: 'Error Validation'
    continueOnError: true # Continue to the next step even if there's an error
```

Also check GCP side event logs if there is any warning or errors in gcp Logging section of the project to troubleshoot in efficient manner.